# Rails will_paginate - how to make nicer route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, routes, will-paginate

I have on the homepage list of articles that are listed with using **will_paginate** gem.
Everything works well, but there is one thing I would want to improve - on the homepage, the data are loaded into **home** controller and **index** action.

So, when I load my website - **www.website.com**, data are loaded into **home/index**. When I click on the pagination link for the second page, the link is **www.website.com/home/index?page=2**. I would like to see there in the best way **www.website.com/page/2** (or **www.website.com/?page=2**).

Basically, the point is to remove from the URL **/home/index** - is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way - add this class to some helper module, for example `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  class SmartLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a? Fixnum
        attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
        target = url(target)
      end
      attributes[:href] = target.gsub(/[?&]page=(\d+)/,'/page/\1')
      tag(:a, text, attributes)
    end
  end

end
```

You may customize it according to your needs, for example do

```
attributes[:href] = target.gsub(/home\/index/,'')
```

or whatever. And then you may do this in your views:

```
<%= will_paginate @items, :renderer => 'ApplicationHelper::SmartLinkRenderer' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

in you config/routes.rb file

**EDIT**

to be able to route these kind of requests: 
www.website.com/page/2

add this to routes.rb:

```
match "page/:page" => "your_root_controller#index"
```

this way *:page* will be in your *params* hash.
and for example index method to view your Message model can be:

```
  def index
    @messages = Messages.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

hope that can help. for more information please refer to [RoR routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: This is set up, that's why **www.website.com** display content from `home#index`.